Make a specific child element define the width of a parent element
I have an element that will look something like this:

My goal is to make that white area sized to those little dots at the top, and the content area to hide any overflow past those dots. The top component can be variable size, so it is not viable to size it with a static size
My first attempt looked something like this:
<section class="flex w-screen h-screen">
  <aside class="grid shrink-0 grid-cols-[max-content] grid-rows-[max-content_1fr]">
    <ul></ul>
    <div class="w-0">
      <div class="flex-1"><!-- content --></div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="grow"></main>
</section>

However, I can't seem to get a content area that renders as the width of the above bar
Any ideas on how this would be done?
Tailwind playground:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/5QyNkEAgtc

The problem is that the div.flex-1 element is overflowing the parent element. This means the truncate of the child div.truncate element has no effect, since its content is not overflowing but rather the parent element is.
You would want to apply the width: 0 to this div.flex-1 element, not its parent. This would mean that the div.flex-1 no longer overflows its parent and adheres to its parent's width. This means the child div.truncate element adheres to this width too. This means the text content of the div.truncate element can overflow, allowing the truncate to have a visible effect.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="flex h-screen w-screen gap-4 bg-gray-100">
  <aside class="grid grid-cols-[max-content] grid-rows-[max-content_1fr] bg-white px-4 py-4">
    <ul class="flex gap-4">
      <ul class="flex h-fit w-fit gap-2 rounded-md px-2 py-4 shadow-md">
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="flex h-fit w-fit gap-2 rounded-md px-2 py-4 shadow-md">
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
        <li class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <div class="mt-5 flex whitespace-nowrap">
      <div class="flex-1 w-0">
        <div class="truncate">Here is all of my content, but I want it to behave like normal</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="flex-grow"></main>
</div>



